# Получить угол поворота элемента jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Задача такова 
есть div блок

```
<div class="trick"></div>
```

в разные моменты времени - его вращает другой скрипт на определенный угол
мне надо получить в переменную на какой угол в данный момент повернуть этот блок

пробовал получить вот так

```
 console.log($('.trick').css('transform'));
```

выдает значения такие  matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

но я к сожалению не могу получить из матрицы свойства transform именно поворот, как это сделать? rotate

Comment: Через математику :)

Comment: в этот топик постучись там ответивший автор очень искушен https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById("thing");
var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
         st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
         "FAIL";
```

Здесь можно почитать подробнее [детально>>>](https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

Атрибут `transform`, в случае когда у элемента установлен `rotate` возвращает матрицу 2д поворота которая ни что иное как:

```
cos(t) -sin(t) 
sin(t)  cos(t) 
  0       0
```

для нахождения угла в декартовой системе координат есть специальная функция `atan2(y, x)`

Искомый угол в радианах можно найти по этой "формуле", соответственно нужно взять из матрицы 2 числа и передать их `atan2`:

`t = atan2(sin(t), cos(t))`

```js
requestAnimationFrame(calc);

function calc(t){
  requestAnimationFrame(calc);

  var tr = getComputedStyle(trick).transform;
  var values = tr.split(/\(|,|\)/);
  // угол в радианах
  var angle = Math.atan2(+values[2], +values[1]); 
  // приводим угол к диапазону 0-360
  val.textContent = ((angle * (180/Math.PI)+360)%360).toFixed(0) 

}
```

```css
#trick {
  padding:50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  animation: 10s rot infinite linear;
}

#trick div{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:solid;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0;
  transform:rotate(135deg)
}

@keyframes rot {
  0%   {transform:rotate(0)}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<div id="val"></div>
<div id="trick"><div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let rotate = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.trick')).transform;

const angle = (i) => {
  let arr = i.match(/-?\d+\.?\d+[^,]/gi);
  let [cos, sin] = [arr[0], arr[1]];

  let degree = Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180 / Math.PI));
  if (cos < 0) {
    addDegree = 90 - Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180 / Math.PI));
    degree = 90 + addDegree;
  }

  if (degree < 0) {
    degree = 360 + degree;
  }

  return degree;

}

console.log(angle(rotate))
```

```css
.trick {
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="trick"></div>
```